# how to get oauth access token and secret for magento using php

Tags: php, magento, oauth

I have consumer key and secret. I tried to get oauth request token using consumer key and secret but my bad i'm getting error which is

> Uncaught exception 'OAuthException' with message 'Invalid auth/bad
>   request (got a 404, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)'

i've tried the below code to get the request token, but it did not work

```
$callbackUrl = "http://www.myhost.com/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://www.myhost.com/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://www.myhost.com/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://www.myhost.com/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://www.myhost.com/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'my consumerKey';
$consumerSecret = 'my consumerSecret';

session_start();

if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}

$authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
$oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
$oauthClient->enableDebug();

if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !isset($_SESSION['state'])) {
    $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
   echo  $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
    $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
    header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
    exit;
} else if (isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
    $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
    $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
    $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
    header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
    exit;
}
print_r($_SESSION);//get this by next page
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: You are getting a 404, which means that the server you are calling is not finding a resource/script at the URL you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that by changing the server configurations to assume the .htaccess rules. Try to check it out.

Comment: You should give more details of how you did it